# Asp Net Core - dependency injection - trace object resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

For debugging purposes, is there a way to trace what type has been resolved when with what scope by the dependency framework within Asp Net Core?

Looking into [IServiceProviderEngineCallback](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/release/2.1/src/DI/ServiceLookup/IServiceProviderEngineCallback.cs)

```
// Copyright (c) .NET Foundation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup
{
    internal interface IServiceProviderEngineCallback
    {
        void OnCreate(IServiceCallSite callSite);
        void OnResolve(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope);
    }
 }
```

and other internal classes... Is there a way to hook into the "OnResolve"?

Comment: maybe implement your own `IServiceScope` and have that publish an event.  pesky `internal`...